# How to initialize and send a toast notification

Tags: c#, xml, toast

I'm trying to initialize and send my toast notification to my uwp and can't get it to recognize the content name, but it always recommends a different content name.

I have an XML file and a C# file that are the same toast notifications and I'm just having the trouble when I'm getting to initialize it and send it to my app.

This is my XML file

```
<toast launch ="app-defined-string" scenario="Reminder">
  <visual>
    <binding template ="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Reminder</text>
      <text>Have you set up all of your arrangements for your trip to St. Petersburg yet? The closer you get to the date, the more expensive flights and excursions will cost!</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
    <action content="Yes I've already made arrangements!" arguments="check" imageUri="check.png"/>
    <action content="No, I haven't yet." arguments="cancel" imageUri="cancel.png"/>
  </actions>
</toast>
```

This is my C# file for roughly the same notification

```
 class ToastNotification
    {
        ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
        {
            Launch = "app-defined string",

            Visual = new ToastVisual()
            {
                BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                {
                    Children =
                     {
                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = "Reminder"
                        },

                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = "Have you set up all of your arrangements for your trip to St. Petersburg yet? The closer you get to the date, the more expensive flights and excursions will cost!"
                        }
                     },
                }

            },


            Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
            {
                Buttons =
                {
                    new ToastButton("Yes I have, thanks!", "thanks"),
                    new ToastButton("No I have not yet!", "later")
                    {
                        ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Foreground
                    }
                }
            }
        };



    }
```

When I try to initialize it I try this in C#:

```
XmlDocument xmlContent = content.GetXml();

ToastNotification notification = new ToastNotification(xmlContent);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
```

The problem I'm having the trouble with is the first line because it won't recognize the content.GetXml(); part; it will suggest something else.